# Send unencoded query parameters in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-query-params

I'm working with an API that only accepts unencoded query parameters. I notice that when I make a query in Ember like so:

`this.store.query('listing', {filter: params});`

The uri is encoded when it hits the api:

`/v1/listing?filter%5Bcategory%5D=123`

What I need is for the query parameters to get to my API unencoded, eg:

`/v1/listing?filter[category]=123`

Can anybody give me a steer on what is the right way to do this in Ember?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution I ended up implementing is not great but it does the trick until I find a better way.

Ember uses Ajax to form the request, so what I did was override 'query' in my JSONAPIAdapter to pass through a custom set of options. My query now looks like this:

```
query(store, type, query) {
  let url = this.buildURL(type.modelName, null, null, 'query', query);
  if (this.sortQueryParams) {
    query = this.sortQueryParams(query);
  }
  query = decodeURI(Ember.$.param(query));
  let options = {
    "processData": false,
    "data": query
  };
  return this.ajax(url, 'GET', options);
},
```

The key was to stop ajax's automatic processing of the data object, and decode the result of jquery's 'param()' helper function, which is used to convert the query param object into a serialized string.

The result is a decoded query param string like so:
`/v1/listing?filter[category]=123`